# Call a member of an object with arguments

Tags: typescript

```
function whatever(object, methodName, args) {
  return object[methodName](...args);
}
```

Can the above be typed so the the following is enforced:

- `methodName` is a key of `object`.
- `object[methodName]` is callable and its args are `...args`.
- The return type of `whatever(object, methodName, args)` is the return type of `object[methodName](...args)`.

The closest thing I could find is the definition of `function.apply`, but it isn't quite the same as the above.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I *think* this does the trick:

```
function callMethodWithArgs<
  M extends keyof T,
  T extends { [m in M]: (...args: Array<any>) => any },
  F extends T[M]
>(obj: T, methodName: M, args: Parameters<F>) {
  return obj[methodName](...args) as ReturnType<F>;
}
```

Requires TS 3 though!

Comment: This [doesn't quite work with generics](https://gist.github.com/jakearchibald/49bb515ab330cf1deb1551232a413b4d), but probably good enough for most situations.

Comment: I should also say: Thank you! TIL I learn `Parameters<F>`, `ReturnType<F>`, and the use of `m in M`.

Comment: Ah yes, hadn't thought about generics in the methods themselves. Sorry it's a bit terse - was going to provide some examples, but... lunch.

Comment: One comment: `<M extends keyof T, ...` makes sure that `methodName` is actually a key of `obj` :)

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley haha nbd big deal

Answer (score 3):

```
type Dictionary = { [key: string]: any }

type MethodNames<T extends Dictionary> = T extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  ? Exclude<keyof [], number>
  : { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? P : never }[keyof T]

function apply<T extends Dictionary, P extends MethodNames<T>>(
  obj: T,
  methodName: P,
  args: Parameters<T[P]>
): ReturnType<T[P]> {
  return obj[methodName](...args);
}

// Testing object types:
const obj = { add: (...args: number[]) => {} }
apply(obj, 'add', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

// Testing array types:
apply([1, 2, 3], 'push', [4])

// Testing the return type:
let result: number = apply(new Map<number, number>(), 'get', [1])
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Dictionary%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MethodNames%3CT%20extends%20Dictionary%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20ReadonlyArray%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20%5B%5D%2C%20number%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20apply%3CT%20extends%20Dictionary%2C%20P%20extends%20MethodNames%3CT%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20obj%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20methodName%3A%20P%2C%0D%0A%20%20args%3A%20Parameters%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20ReturnType%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20obj%5BmethodName%5D(...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Testing%20object%20types%3A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20add%3A%20(...args%3A%20number%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aapply(obj%2C%20'add'%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Testing%20array%20types%3A%0D%0Aapply(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20'push'%2C%20%5B4%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Testing%20the%20return%20type%3A%0D%0Alet%20result%3A%20number%20%3D%20apply(new%20Map%3Cnumber%2C%20number%3E()%2C%20'get'%2C%20%5B1%5D))

The `Dictionary` type allows `T[P]` to be used.

The `Parameters` and `ReturnType` types are baked into TypeScript.

The `MethodNames` type extracts any keys whose value is assignable to the `Function` type. Array types require a special case.

#### Checklist

- Method name is validated? ✅
- Arguments are type-checked? ✅
- Return type is correct? ✅

Comment: The return type comes back as `any`.

Comment: Forgot the `ReturnType`. Fixed

Comment: It now works similarly to the accepted answer (and has the same pitfall).

Answer (score 2):

Is the return type always the same of someObject[methodName]?

```
function whatever<O extends {[key: string]: (...args) => R}, R>(object: O, methodName: keyof O, ...args: any[]): R {
  return object[methodName](...args);
}
```

Then you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. This checks for the `methodName` as well as each of the `args`.

(Note: not perfect, some refinement can be made; e.g., `unknown` -> `any`)

```
type ArgumentsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

function whatever<
  T extends object,
  TKey extends keyof T,
  TArgs extends ArgumentsType<T[TKey]>
>(
  object: T,
  methodName: T[TKey] extends ((...args: TArgs) => unknown) ? TKey : never,
  args: TArgs
): T[TKey] extends ((...args: TArgs) => unknown) ? ReturnType<T[TKey]> : never {
  const method = object[methodName];
  if (typeof method !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('not a function');
  }
  return method(...args);
}

interface Test {
  foo: (a: number, b: number) => number;
  bar: string;
}

const test: Test = {
  foo: (a, b) => a + b,
  bar: 'not a function'
};

const result = whatever(test, 'foo', [1, 2]);
```

Comment: Please link the source of the code snippet: https://twitter.com/DasSurma/status/1083352705475772417

Comment: Great example! it seems to be working correctly, even though I get a compiler warning for this line:  ```): T[TKey] extends ((...args: TArgs) => unknown) ? ReturnType<T[TKey]> : never {````

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function whatever(someObject: { [key: string]: Function}, methodName: string, args: any[]) {
    return someObject[methodName](...args);
}

whatever({ func1: (args) => (console.log(...args)) }, 'func1', [1])
```

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't infer the types of function arguments and the return type. Also won't work if you have object with mixed function and value fields.

Answer (score 1):

The closest result I can think of so far is the following

```
    function whatever<T extends object>(object: T, methodName: keyof T, args: any) {
        const func = object[methodName]
        if (typeof func === "function") {
            return func(...[args])
        }
    }

    const obj = {
      aValue: 1,
      aFunc: (s: string) => "received: " + s
    }

    whatever(obj, "aFunc", "blabla")
```

which correctly checks the key for being part of the object.
The type inference for return type and args is still missing though. I will update the answer if I find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The option that is the type-safest one is to use `Parameters` to get the parameter types of the function (in order for arguments to be type safe), `ReturnType` to return the result of a function.

You also need to also add a type parameter to capture the actual key passed in so we can get the actual type of the function (`T[K]`(

```
function whatever<T extends Record<string, (...a: any[])=> any>, K extends keyof T> (someObject: T,  methodName: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>) : ReturnType<T[K]>{
    return someObject[methodName](...args);
}

whatever({ func1: (args: number[]) => (console.log(...args)) }, 'func1', [1])
whatever({ func1: (args: number[]) => (console.log(...args)) }, 'func1', ["1"]) // err
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, meets all criteria and doesn't need type assertions.

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

function whatever<
  T extends Record<PropertyKey, AnyFunction>,
  K extends keyof T,
  A extends Parameters<T[K]>
>(object: T, methodName: K, args: A): ReturnType<T[K]> {
    return object[methodName](...args);
}
```

The `Parameters` type is a part of the standard library since TypeScript 3.1. If you're using an older version, create it yourself:

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  T extends (...args: infer P) => any
    ? P
    : never;
```

Using the `PropertyKey` type instead of `string` allows you to use properties of type `string | number | symbol`, which is the full gamut supported by JavaScript.